# How to understand --step option in RRD?

Tags: rrdtool

Am I correct that value of `--step` option is used solely for pre-calculating the data slots in RRD? Or does RRD somehow expect updates with interval specified with `--step`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RRDtool will 're-sample' the data you provide to be in `--step` interval before continuing to process it. You can deliver as many updates as you wish. RRDtool will take them all into account when building the `--step` interval.